# Stop event from bubbling to the children

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, event-bubbling

I thought I grasped the concept of bubbling, but now it seems I have not. I created this semi-modal dialog:

```
<div class="context-menu">
    <div class="menu">
        …
    </div>
</div>
```

The .context-menu is position: fixed and takes the whole screen. It has a transparent black background (like a classic modal dialog). The menu is smaller with a white background and is positioned in the center. I want to close this dialog when clicking in the outer area. Therefore, I added an `EventListener` "click" to the `.context-menu` Element. On that click I remove the whole element (display: none on the `.context-menu`). So far so good.

The problem is, that the click seems to also bubble down. So if I click inside the `.menu` element the event fires also (note: the `.menu` is not transparent). I thought events are supposed to bubble upwards (to the parents), not downwards (to the children). I can’t seem to figure out how to prevent this. I tried `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` in all combinations on both elements. It’s always the same result. Every click inside as well as outside the `.menu` element fires the event.

Can you help me out? What do I do wrong?

Comment: _"So if I click inside the .menu element the event fires also"_ - As it should, because the event bubbles "up" to `.context-menu` o.O

Comment: Well, true. But if I add another click EventListener to .menu and add e.stopPropagation, to this, the event on .context-menu still fires :/

Comment: You might want to re-think your question. The title makes the assumption that events bubble "down", The text then talks about the defined behavior of event bubbling and in the comments you're talking about clicking a child and again the defined behavior of event bubbling.

Comment: That said... I cannot reproduce your problem mentioned in the comments: https://jsfiddle.net/7ma3u82t/

Comment: I’m very sorry. I made a bad mistake. My EventListener on .context-menu had the useCapture set to true. I corrected this by mistake, and now it works! 
Sorry that I bothered you with that :/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't want to hide the modal dialog when clicking inside the `.menu` element. It can be done with that code:

```
const container = document.querySelector(".context-menu");
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
container.addEventListener("click", e => {
    if (!menu.contains(e.target)) {
    container.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

I used the `target` property of the event. It shows which element was clicked. If the click was outside of `.menu`, then the function hides the container element